# How do I create a rule to display a system message to users before 10 minutes of an event?

Tags: 7

I am developing a telecalling management system in drupal 7. I have a content type 'Leads' which has a field 'Next Call date'. It is a date field. I want to remind the online user who created the lead(content) about the next call time by a system message. How can I create rule for it?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just a rule. You would need some custom JavaScript that will do the timing in the background and then show the message.

Comment: To add. You can use a rule I guess, but that would require the user to reload or change the page before they will see it.